# Is it ever explained how Coraline's parents were abducted?

Tags: coraline

You have to go through the tiny door in the wall to reach the otherworld, and adults would be too big to fit in it. So how would Coraline's parents reach the otherworld (if they even tried) or would have been abducted by the other mother while still on the Earth? Is this ever explained anywhere? If there are other means to connect the otherworld with Earth, one might think Coraline isn't safe even

> after the key and the hand are thrown into the well.

Comment: Dragged through in their sleep, I expect. They'd easily fit if supine.

Comment: In the film they're in a snowglobe. That would easily fit into a small door

Comment: @Valorum Yeah but how they'd get in there? And I don't think they would fit into the tunnel even in a lying position. Also they probably didn't go to sleep but started to look for their daughter.

Comment: In the original story, the door is just a door, in fact large sized; "*Of the doors that she found, thirteen opened and closed. The other—the big, carved, brown wooden door at the far corner of the drawing room—was locked. She said to her mother, “Where does that door go?” “Nowhere, dear.”"*

Comment: @Valorum So the snowglobe trap is only in the movie?

Comment: The movie is quite faithful to the book. Her parents are in the snowglobe in both.

Comment: @Valorum And how did Coraline save her parents in the book (spoiler warning)? In the very same way as in the movie, bringing the snowglobe back home where the other snowglobe is broken and her parents appear out of nowhere?

Comment: In the book she brings the snowglobe and the marbles through the door, then settles down to sleep in an armchair. She's awoken by her mother, suggesting that the whole thing was a dream. Then she has to fight the Beldam's hand.

Comment: @Valorum That's a bit different from the movie (spoiler warning) where she brings the globe and the marbles (the poor souls' eyes) home, the globe is no longer there and their own snowglobe is broken, and Coraline's parents suddenly enter as if from outside, and don't remember anything. The souls now released thank Coraline and warn her about the hand and the key, so Coraline is going to drown it in the well.